# How does model theory handle limit of a set of formulas

Tags: logic, model-theory

Suppose $f_n$ be $n^{th}$ formula of finite length, and $\bigwedge\limits_{k<n}f_k\to F(\omega)$ as $n\to\omega$, where $F(\omega)$ is an infinitary formula. I'd like to know how it is handled in model theory. In other words, how does (infinitary) model theory treat the limit of formulas of finite length?

Comment: What do you mean by "handle" (or "treat")?

Comment: How to rigorously consider the limit in this case in model theory?

Comment: Please do not down vote. I did have this problem in studying a $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1, \omega_1}$ formula. Since it is not $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1, \omega}$, it could be in untapped territory, and I will post it tomorrow.

Comment: I downvoted. I understand you intend to add more context, but until you do the question is very unclear. I'll consider reversing my vote (and voting to reopen) if the question later turns into one that admits an answer.

Comment: What does it even mean to say that one formula is the limit of a sequence of formulas? Basically, my immediate response to "how does (infinitary) model theory treat the limit of formulas of finite length?" is "it doesn't - 'limit of formulas' isn't a concept used there. (As an aside, $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega_1}$ is not at all untapped territory, it's quite well understood (although not well *behaved*, compared to $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$ or even $\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\omega}$.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question, but I'll give it a go:

If $(\varphi_n)_\omega$ is a countable family of formulas, then (in [certain logics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitary_logic), like $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1 \omega}$) we can form the formula

$$ \bigwedge_{n \in \omega} \varphi_n $$

We say that a model $\mathfrak{M}$ satisfies a formula of the above type whenever it satisfies each of the $\varphi_n$ in turn. That is

$$ \mathfrak{M} \models \bigwedge_{n \in \omega} \varphi_n \iff  \mathfrak{M} \models \varphi_n \text{ for every $n \in \omega$}$$

As a cultural note, in my experience logicians don't view these as being "limits" of finite conjunctions. Infinitary conjunctions and disjunctions are pieces of syntax just like any other.

If you want a good resource for working with these logics, and rigorously considering these kinds of conjunctions (as you've expressed in the comments), I recommend [this pdf](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~marker/math512-F13/inf.pdf) on Infinitary Logic by David Marker

---

**Edit:** For larger logics yet, the standard reference is Dickmann's [Larger Infinitary Languages](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pl/1235417275), but as a quick summary of the semantics, say 
$\overline{v}$ is a family of less than $\lambda$ variables and $\varphi$ is a formula which has (possibly a subset of) the $\overline{v}$ free. Then

$$ \exists \overline{v}. \varphi(\overline{v}) $$

$$ \forall \overline{v}. \varphi(\overline{v}) $$

are both formulas, and

$$ 
\mathfrak{M} \models \exists \overline{v}. \varphi(\overline{v})
\iff
\text{There are elements } \overline{x} \in \mathfrak{M}^\lambda
\text{ so that } \mathfrak{M} \models \varphi(\overline{x})
$$

$$ 
\mathfrak{M} \models \forall \overline{v}. \varphi(\overline{v})
\iff
\text{Every vector of elements } \overline{x} \in \mathfrak{M}^\lambda
\text{ satisfies } \mathfrak{M} \models \varphi(\overline{x})
$$

Infinitary conjunctions and disjunctions are still defined as above, but with possibly more than $\omega$ many formulas.

As an example (paraphrased from Dickmann):

> In $\mathcal{L}_{\kappa^+ \kappa}$ we can assert that a model has cardinality $< \kappa$:
>
> $$ 
> \bigvee_{\text{Cardinals } \lambda < \kappa} 
> (\exists (v_\alpha)_{\alpha < \lambda} . 
> \left [ 
> \bigwedge_{\gamma \neq \delta < \lambda}
> (v_\gamma \neq v_\delta) \land \forall y . \bigvee_{\gamma < \lambda} (y = v_\gamma)
> \right ]
> $$

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1 \omega_1}$ is also well studied. For an overview, Dickmann's [Larger Infinitary Languages](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pl/1235417275) is standard. I'll edit my answer to include these semantics as well

Comment: Thanks. I just found this helpful and accepted your answer.